# Freeze header in pandas dataframe

Tags: python-2.7, pandas

Is there a way by which I can freeze Pandas data frame header { as we do in excel}.So if its a long dataframe with multiple rows we can see the headers once we scroll down!!  I am assuming ipython notebook

Comment: did you ever figure this one out?

Comment: No I was not able to figure out

Answer (score 24):

This function may do the trick:

```
from ipywidgets import interact, IntSlider
from IPython.display import display

def freeze_header(df, num_rows=30, num_columns=10, step_rows=1,
                  step_columns=1):
    """
    Freeze the headers (column and index names) of a Pandas DataFrame. A widget
    enables to slide through the rows and columns.

    Parameters
    ----------
    df : Pandas DataFrame
        DataFrame to display
    num_rows : int, optional
        Number of rows to display
    num_columns : int, optional
        Number of columns to display
    step_rows : int, optional
        Step in the rows
    step_columns : int, optional
        Step in the columns

    Returns
    -------
    Displays the DataFrame with the widget
    """
    @interact(last_row=IntSlider(min=min(num_rows, df.shape[0]),
                                 max=df.shape[0],
                                 step=step_rows,
                                 description='rows',
                                 readout=False,
                                 disabled=False,
                                 continuous_update=True,
                                 orientation='horizontal',
                                 slider_color='purple'),
              last_column=IntSlider(min=min(num_columns, df.shape[1]),
                                    max=df.shape[1],
                                    step=step_columns,
                                    description='columns',
                                    readout=False,
                                    disabled=False,
                                    continuous_update=True,
                                    orientation='horizontal',
                                    slider_color='purple'))
    def _freeze_header(last_row, last_column):
        display(df.iloc[max(0, last_row-num_rows):last_row,
                        max(0, last_column-num_columns):last_column])
```

Test it with:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(pd.np.random.RandomState(seed=0).randint(low=0,
                                                           high=100,
                                                           size=[200, 50]))
freeze_header(df=df, num_rows=10)
```

It results in (the colors were customized in the `~/.jupyter/custom/custom.css` file):
[image]

Comment: Neat solution, however if your data fluctuates in width (i.e. a string of 100 characters vs a string of 20) then the columns will jump around as you scroll which makes it difficult to follow. Any thoughts on a workaround for that?

Comment: This is great, but it drops styling for the pandas dataframe. For example, the heatmap I'm trying to generate no longer takes effect

corr.style.background_gradient(cmap='coolwarm').set_precision(2)

Answer (score 10):

Old question but wanted to revisit it because I recently found a solution. Use the qgrid module: https://github.com/quantopian/qgrid

This will not only allow you to scroll with the headers frozen but also sort, filter, edit inline and some other stuff. Very helpful.

Comment: This worked for me. However, note that Qgrid on its Github page is not tested in Jupyter lab 3.0. Thus if using Jupyter lab 3 try the installation method listed here https://github.com/quantopian/qgrid/issues/350

Comment: Unfortunately, qgrid hasn't been updated since 2020, and it is no longer compatible with recent versions of Jupyter.

Answer (score 7):

Try panda's [Sticky Headers](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/style.html#Sticky-Headers):

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

bigdf = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(16, 100))
bigdf.style.set_sticky(axis="index")
```

(this feature was introduced lately, I found it working on pandas 1.3.1, but not on 1.2.4)

Comment: This contains code similar to the above but which actually works in my jupyter version https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/29072

Comment: AttributeError: 'Styler' object has no attribute 'set_sticky'

Answer (score 0):

A solution that would work on any editor is to select what rows you want to look at:

```
df.ix[100:110] # would show you from row 101 to 110 keeping the header on top
```