# Pandastable: Freeze columns

Tags: python, pandas

Has anyone figures out a way to freeze certain cells/columns in pandastable? E.g., allow a user to scroll to the right but have the first two columns stay visible? It is extremely common in Excel, but can't figure out how to code such a thing in pandastable.

Comment: I think it's a great question. Quite some people really don't want to use Excel, but it does have some great features, such as freeze panes. I just tried the jupyter extension qgrid, but it also didnt have this feature, so I think your solution of creating an index is a good idea. This maybe in combination with: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28778668/freeze-header-in-pandas-dataframe

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to set the columns you want frozen as the index, then use the pt.showIndex() command. It isn't the ideal solution since that could foul up some other part of your DataFrame, but it works in my specific case.

```
pt = Table(table_frame, dataframe=df)
pt.showIndex()
pt.show()
```

Comment: @RileyHun: I just used `table_frame` as a stand-in for whatever frame you might put your PandasTable in. There aren't any special imports if you are already using PandasTable.