# Pandas - Repeat headings every n-th row in Jupyter-lab notebook

Tags: python, pandas

Is there a way to repeat the headings (column titles) of a Pandas dataframe every n-th row in a Jupyter-lab notebook.

I normally use `pd.set_option('display.max_columns', None)` with pandas in a Jupyter-lab notebook, since I want to view all the columns and data. However when showing more than 10 rows the scroll bar at the bottom is hidden when viewing the headings and the headings are hidden when viewing the scroll bar; which makes it very difficult to know what you are seeing or to know where to scroll to.

Is there a way to repeat the headings every n-th row or is it possible to have a vertical scrollbar as well with the headings then always remaining visible.

Comment: Similar question answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28778668/freeze-header-in-pandas-dataframe

Comment: Thanks, doesn't really work great but definitely better than the standard behaviour.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple `print()` can do what you need. You can try this code.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

# generate a dataframe with many rows, say, 40.
randn = np.random.randn
df1 = pd.DataFrame(randn(40, 4).round(2), columns=['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'])

start = 0
for ea in range(0, len(df1), 10):
    # will print 10 rows of data in each loop
    if (start != ea):
        print("From row:%s" % start, "to row:%s" % (ea-1))
        # print certain rows of the dataframe
        print(df1.iloc[start:ea])
        print()
    start = ea
```

The output:

```
From row:0 to row:9
      A     B     C     D
0  0.57  0.90 -0.74 -0.82
1  0.46  1.44 -1.42  0.90
2  1.08  0.18  1.73 -0.64
3 -2.32 -0.89  0.62  0.35
4  0.19  0.51 -0.79 -0.37
5 -0.41  0.78  0.12 -1.88
6  0.53 -0.60 -0.29 -1.45
7  1.54  0.01  0.12  0.72
8 -1.65  0.36 -2.61  1.81
9  0.23 -1.23  0.46  1.17

From row:10 to row:19
       A     B     C     D
10  1.02 -1.14 -2.11  0.69
11  1.30  0.27  1.80  0.39
12  0.43  0.70  0.23 -0.84
13 -0.14 -1.29  0.31  0.34
14  1.94  0.16 -0.86  1.19
15 -0.43 -2.05  1.69 -0.98
16 -0.54 -0.59 -0.70 -0.29
17  1.34 -0.04 -1.02 -0.19
18  1.47 -0.53  1.09  1.15
19 -0.04  1.13 -1.27 -1.09

From row:20 to row:29
       A     B     C     D
20 -0.16  1.39  0.35 -0.16
21  0.79  0.12 -1.22 -0.55
22 -1.16 -0.29  0.14  0.33
23  1.59 -0.26 -0.01  1.07
24 -0.76 -2.46  0.08  0.35
25  0.29  2.07 -0.96  0.63
26  0.85 -1.08  1.19  1.71
27 -0.36  0.00  0.87 -0.50
28  0.07  0.84  0.80  0.00
29 -0.16 -0.43  1.51 -1.24
```

Edit 1

Another approach:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from IPython.display import HTML
from random import choice
from string import ascii_uppercase

# Generate data for demo
rows = 36
cols = 6

def rand_colhdr(num=3):
    return ''.join(choice(ascii_uppercase) for i in range(num))

col_hdrs = [rand_colhdr(num=3) for ix in range(cols)]

randn = np.random.randn
df1 = pd.DataFrame(randn(rows, cols).round(2), columns=col_hdrs)

# Code to gen a table as HTML, taking data from pandas dataframe 
rows = len(df1)         #take all rows
cols = len(df1.columns) #take all columns

# Every `rowgrp` section need its own header
rowgrp = 8
col_hdrs = [acol for acol in df1.columns]
col_hdrs = ["row#"]+col_hdrs

div_tplt = "<div><table>{0}</table></div>"
str2rep = "<tr>"+''.join(["<th>"+str(ea)+"</th>" for ea in col_hdrs])+"</tr>"

#str2rep = head_row
for arow in range(rows):
    td_code = ""

    th_code = ""
    if (arow%rowgrp == 0 and arow > 0):
        # do header rows
        for acol in range(1+len(df1.columns)):
            # use columns' name from dataframe

            #th_code += '<td>'+ '<b>Col:'+str(acol) +'</b></td>'+"\n"
            th_code += '<td>'+ '<b>'+ col_hdrs[acol] +'</b></td>'+"\n"
        row_tp = "<tr>{0}</tr>".format(th_code)
        str2rep += row_tp.format()

    for acol in range(1+len(df1.columns)):
        # do regular row data
        if acol==0: #do row-index
            td_code += '<td>'+str(arow+1)+'</td>'+"\n"
            pass
        else:
            # use the content of cell(arow,acol) from dataframe
            td_code += '<td>'+ repr(df1.iloc[arow, acol-1]) +'</td>'+"\n"

    row_tp = "<tr>{0}</tr>".format(td_code)
    str2rep += row_tp.format()

HTML(div_tplt.format(str2rep))
```

[image]

Comment: I'm looking for something that works with `df.head()`

Comment: @Superdooperhero Not possible with `df.head()` or `df.tail()`. I advise you to look into their sorce code, and create the missing `df.body()` for use.