# How to Freeze Index and Column in Pandas DataFrame But Also Maintain Styling in Jupyter Notebook?

Tags: python, excel, pandas, formatting, styling

I'm trying to display a correlation heatmap which has 100 columns. I was investigating some options that allow one to do the Excel-equivalent of "Freeze pane", but all of them that I've looked into drop the styling. How do I freeze the index/headers and also include styling?

```
corr = numeric_data.dropna(how='all').corr()
def condense_text(text,pos):
    text = list(text)
    for i in range(pos,len(text),pos):
        text.insert(i, '\n')
    return "".join(text)

corr.columns = [condense_text(c,8) for c in corr.columns.tolist()]
corr.style.background_gradient(cmap='coolwarm').set_precision(2)
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28778668/freeze-header-in-pandas-dataframe Have you considered looking at this?

Comment: This might also help you https://mode.com/example-gallery/python_dataframe_styling/

Comment: Yup the links you've showed are exactly what I implemented. But you can't combine both styling and the freeze_header function together it seems